# How to insert pageview in google analytics using c# analytics api v3

Tags: google-analytics

I created a goal in Google analytics for tracking all page views which starts with /phone/ s.t. i can track the pages which starts with /phone/.

The problem is I want to track page without tracking code.

Is there any way to generate page view through c# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually enter pageviews to Google analytics using a simple browser you don't need to go as far as using C#.  That being said you can also use C# since all you need to do is a HTTP GET or POST and that can be done in C# as well.

You will need to look into the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/)  I have a tutorial that shows how to do it with a [Application Google Analytics account](http://www.daimto.com/monitoring-quota-usage-for-google-apis/) which uses screen views instead of page views.  It should be possible to edit that.   The main difference is you wont need to send all the Application account required fields.   You will have to figure out which pages you want to send and send that as Document location URL.

If you have any problems let me know I would be happy to help you work this out.

Comment: Hey thanks for reply. I tried a lot, I am hitting                       "http://www.google-analytics.com?v=1&tid=UA-XXXXXXX-1&cid=555&t=pageview&dh=www.pomroofing.com&dp=/phone/123/456/789/1&dt=homepage " using post but there is no page view in my analytics account can you please help.